# How to change UnrealEngine to use BuildTool 2022 instead of 2019

Tags: visual-studio-code, unreal-engine5

Currently my Unreal Engine 5 is using Visual Studio build Tool 2019 to build as it was previously installed in my PC. I was wondering if I can change my Unreal Engine 5 to use Build Tool 2022 instead of 2019 version.

Answer (score 3):

1. Find your BuildConfiguration.xml file. It can be in several places, I suggest you pick one location and delete the other ones. I used the one in

   C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\UnrealBuildTool\BuildConfiguration.xml

The other locations are Engine/Saved/UnrealBuildTool/BuildConfiguration.xml
and
My Documents/Unreal Engine/UnrealBuildTool/BuildConfiguration.xml

2. Inside the Configuration tags, add the following:

> ```
> <VCProjectFileGenerator>
>     <Version>VisualStudio2022</Version>
> </VCProjectFileGenerator>
> <WindowsPlatform>
>     <Compiler>VisualStudio2022</Compiler>
> </WindowsPlatform>
> ```

You might not have to restart Unreal for the setting to take.
As of Jan 2023, that's what worked for me, for Unreal Engine 5.1. I'm still getting IncrediBuild lincense errors, but at least the above should get you past the Visual Studio 2022 version issue.

Source: https://store.algosyntax.com/tutorials/unreal-engine/ue5-visual-studio-2019-must-be-installed-in-order-to-build-this-target/ Thanks Algosyntax!